# Page is going blank after json response in laravel

Tags: php, json, sockets, laravel, chat

Edit: Here's a little video of my problem: [The video](https://youtu.be/hKsLdsQhgE0)

I'm working on my socket based chat app in laravel 5.2. I was basing on [this](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-52-chat-message-module-using-socketio-redis-express-and-nodejs-from-from-scratchexample.html) tutorial. Here's what I do and what's the problem:

1. I run my mysql server
2. I run redis-server
3. I run 'node server.js'
4. I run 'sudo php artisan serve --port=80'
5. I enter my site in the browser
6. I log in
7. I'm redirected to chat page
8. I enter an massage and send it
9. Page goes all white with '[]' being the only content

After running chat in two browsers and sending an message in one of them, the message appears properly on the other one. I'm running OS X ElCaptain.

Here's my routes file:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

// Route::get('/chat', 'ChatController@index');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/chat', 'ChatController@index');
});
Route::post('sendmessage', 'ChatController@sendMessage');
```

Here's my ChatController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Request;
use LRedis;

class ChatController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        // $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function index() {
        return view('chat.index');
    }

    public function sendMessage() {
        $redis = LRedis::connection();
        $data = [
            'message' => Request::input('message'),
            'user'    => Request::input('user')
        ];
        $redis->publish('message', json_encode($data));

        /*
        Content-Type is set to text/html because otherwise there was an error
        in JavaScript console.log:
        Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type application/json.
         */
        return response()->json([])->header('Content-Type', 'text/html');

    }
}
```

Here's my view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'CityChat')

@section('styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/chat/index.css') }}">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
@endsection

@section('scripts')
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/chat/index.js') }}"></script>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div id="chat" class="ui container">
        <div class="ui grid">
            <div class="four wide column">
                <div id="users" class="ui segment">
                    <div class="ui list">
                        (div.item>strong{username$})*50
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="twelve wide column">
                <div id="messages" class="ui top attached segment">

                </div>
                <div class="ui bottom attached segment">
                    <form action="sendmessage" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" >
                        <div class="ui fluid transparent input">
                            <input class="msg" type="text" name="message" placeholder="Tu wpisz swoją wiadomość">
                            <button type="button" class="ui button send">Wyślij</button>
                            {{-- <input type="button" class="send-msg" name="send" value="Send"> --}}
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Of course jquery is implemented in layouts.app before the index.js, which is:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8890');
socket.on('message', function(data) {
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(data.user);
    $("#messages").append("<p><strong>" + data.user + ":</strong> " + data.message + "</p>");
});
$(".send").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var token = $("input[name ='_token']").val();
    var user  = $("input[name ='user']").val();
    var msg   = $(".msg").val();
    if (msg != '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '{!! URL::to("sendmessage") !!}',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                '_token': token,
                'message': msg,
                'user': user
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log();
                $(".msg").val('');
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Please Add Message.");
    }
})
```

And here's the server.js

```
var app    = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io     = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis  = require('redis');

server.listen(8890);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log("client connected");
    var redisClient = redis.createClient();
    redisClient.subscribe('message');

    redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) {
        console.log("mew message add in queue " + data['message'] + " channel");
        socket.emit(channel, data);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        redisClient.quit();
    });
});
```

I don't know what else could be helpful. I hope you will help me guys :)

Comment: So the problem is that "Page goes all white with '[]' being the only content
" ? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: The expected behavior is to display the new message in the chat window and don't refresh page at all. I added a little video to my question so everyone can see clearly what's happening :)

Comment: Your sendMessage() method returns an empty json object.

Comment: Why is that happening and what can I do to fix it? Even if I comment out entire return line the page goes blank.